# Why do we say 'He is Fred to a t'?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I used to think it was only a British idiom.

But I read an article in the New York Times stressing how important tea was to the British army in Iraq. Apparently there is even a special attachment on a Challenger Tank for making a decent cup of tea. But the article was headed, punningly:

THE BRITISH TO A T.

Sometimes people will say of a child 'He is his father to a t'. Why a 't'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the original phrase is 'to a tittle' as in 'Not a jot nor a tittle out of place'.

Those phrases referred to writing Greek and meant literally that even the very small markings including subscript iotas (jots) and the diacritical markings that indicate tone and breathing  (including what we would call a tilde, but before Spanish inflected it, a tittle) were correctly copied throughout an entire passage.

So if one person looked as much like another as a perfectly copied manuscript, that was pretty similar.

My best guess as to why to abbreviate 'tittle' to 'T' would be prudery.  It sounds too much like a reference to women's breasts?  Clearly the original usage was monastic, clerical, schoolboys or something, or they would not choose references to copying Greek.  So perhaps prudery ran really high.

Comment: This matches the least popular offering at the duplicate question.  (Quotes from the Book of Luke aside.)

Comment: +1 and a tick, but why do you say it matches the 'least popular offering'. It appears to match the most popular If the abbreviation to T was about prudery the most likely time for change was probably the Victorian period.

Comment: Actually, it is 'to a T' from pretty early, so I would not lay it on the Victorians, but on biblical translators.  And yeah, I did not look close enough.  The same answer is given twice there, and obviously this agrees with both instances.

Comment: Then I doubt it was 'prudery'. That was not really invented until the 19th century.

Comment: You are kidding.  You remember that part of the Bible where Esau backs slowly into his ailing father's tent to get blessed because the old man is naked, and too weak to dress?  These were adult males, (whether that means the characters, or the authors, does not matter).  Prudery is pretty old.

Comment: I'm not sufficiently an Old Testament scholar to be able to comment. But the idea of changing names of things, (in North America, 'cock' becomes 'rooster', 'arse' becomes 'ass' etc) is quintessentially 19th century. They also covered table legs with long table-cloths so no suggestion of the female form was conveyed etc. In Chaucer's time people would, without hesitation, have spoken of 'tits', 'arses', 'farting' and 'pissing'. Gentility is a feature of a developing bourgeois society, which reaches its apotheosis in Victoria's reign and image. (I'm not commenting on her servant, John Brown!)

Comment: My impression is that prudery goes up and down as the tide.  There are times when this happens, and times when it does not.  To go all old-testament on you again. -- "This too is vanity, for there is nothing new under the sun."

Comment: Remember that between 1800 and 1900 the world changed out of all recognition. Population simply exploded, and people's lives in cities was unlike anything hitherto; demanding a vast new professional class that had never before existed. Notions of gentility were among the things that defined them. They were hugely influential on the whole of society. People in the 1790s were probably living lives more similar to the Old Testament characters, than to those of their great grandchildren a hundred years later. Something 'new under the sun' did arise, it was  called *industrialisation*.